# How to fix"error while loading shared libraries: libgl.so.1"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

After I run this command `dpkg -l |grep ^rc|awk '{print $2}' |sudo xargs dpkg -P`

I got the problem while opening smplayer,cairo-dock,unity-2d-shell and amdconfig ,"error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".   Maybe there are other applications would meet the same problem.

But I do have the file

```
locate libGL.so.1  
/usr/lib/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1.2



ldd $(which unity-2d-shell)|grep libGL  
libGL.so.1 => not found        
ldd $(which mplayer)|grep not  
libGL.so.1 => not found
```

But

```
ldd $(which smplayer)|grep libGL
```

got nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Braiam is spot on. You should also know that finding a file with `locate` does not mean it exists. `locate` uses a database that is refreshed every now and then. It does not search the actual file systsem but it's database. You can run `updatedb` to refresh the database before searching or use the `-e` flag:

```
-e, --existing
     Print only entries that refer to files existing at the time locate is run.
```

For example:

```
$ touch stupid_stupid_file.txt
$ locate stupid_stupid_file.txt   ## No results
$ sudo updatedb                   ## refresh database
$ locate stupid_stupid_file.txt
/home/terdon/stupid_stupid_file.txt  ## the file was found after updatedb
$ rm stupid_stupid_file.txt          ## delete the file
$ locate stupid_stupid_file.txt
/home/terdon/stupid_stupid_file.txt   ## the file is still in the database 
$ locate -e stupid_stupid_file.txt   ## the file is not found using -e
```

Comment: It's weird. I have rebooted. But it seems like didn't update the database. And after that, it turns out that that package dose not exists. But using "apt-get install" , I can't find that package. Using "apt-file search", many package include this lib, and how can i install that lib correctly?

Comment: @Ziu you need to run `updatedb` to update the database, rebooting is irrelevant. Anyway, check the dependencies of mplayer: `apt-cache depends mplayer | grep -i libgl` that will return the packages that `mplayer` depends on. One of them should be `libgl1-mesa-glx`.

Comment: Finally fix it. It is libgl1-mes-glx, but when I try to install that, it reminds me have installed the latest version. Then I thought that maybe it is something wrong with the graphics drive. So i uninstall it, and it works correctly. and the libGL:`libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f1e83fa7000)`. Then i install the amd drive again, and it still works. But the dependency changes. libGL:`libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fe24e687000)` .  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because some linked libraries got broken when you uninstalled several package at once. You should have run `dpkg -l |grep ^rc|awk '{print $2}'` before hand to know what will happen. Luckily this can be solved using `sudo ldconfig`. This recreates the linked libraries cache and will (hopefully) fix your libraries.

Of course, that will only works if you really have the `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1` library installed:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 sep 18 14:03 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
dpkg -S libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

(mine is 64bits that's why the difference.)

Comment: It's my fault. TI don't have the /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 actually. How can I install that lib?